# Actualizar fila en TableView - JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

Mi problema es que tengo una interfaz de un punto de venta de una tienda, donde quiero agregar varias veces un producto en mi TableView pero que este no se repita, como muestro en la imagen, quiero lograr que al agregar la cantidad de dos y después volver a agregar otros dos a la cantidad de ese producto este se actualice a cuatro y no me cree otra fila como muestro en la imagen.
Alguna sugerencia de como puedo resolverlo?

```
@FXML
private void agregarProducto(ActionEvent event) {
    String codigo, nombre, tipoAlimento, precio, cantidad, importe;
    if(txtCodigoProductoBuscar.getText().isEmpty() || txtCantidadProductos.getText().isEmpty()){
        Alert dialogoAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        dialogoAlert.setTitle("Agregar producto");
        dialogoAlert.setHeaderText(null);
        dialogoAlert.setContentText("Rellene todos los campos por favor.");
        dialogoAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        dialogoAlert.showAndWait();
    }else{
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Codigo='".concat(txtCodigoProductoBuscar.getText()).concat("'");
        try {
            prep = cn.prepareStatement(consulta);
            result = prep.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                codigo = result.getString(2);
                nombre = result.getString(3);
                tipoAlimento = result.getString(4);
                precio = result.getString(5);
                cantidad = txtCantidadProductos.getText();
                int precioProducto = Integer.parseInt(precio);
                int cantidadProducto = Integer.parseInt(cantidad);
                importe = String.valueOf(precioProducto * cantidadProducto);
                datosProductoVenta.add(new DatosProductosVenta(codigo, nombre, tipoAlimento, precio, cantidad, importe));
                Alert dialogoAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                dialogoAlert.setTitle("Agregar producto");
                dialogoAlert.setHeaderText(null);
                dialogoAlert.setContentText("Producto agregado correctamente.");
                dialogoAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                dialogoAlert.showAndWait();
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Alert dialogoAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            dialogoAlert.setTitle("Agregar producto");
            dialogoAlert.setHeaderText(null);
            dialogoAlert.setContentText("El producto no fue encontrado.");
            dialogoAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            dialogoAlert.showAndWait();
        }
        tbvDatosProductosVenta.setItems(datosProductoVenta);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer primero, antes de ir a buscar el producto a la base de datos, es buscarlo en la tabla, y si lo encuentras, solo actualizas en la tabla (de la GUI) la cantidad y el importe.

> Este es el código que debe ir dentro de tu `else`

```
    codigo = txtCodigoProductoBuscar.getText();
    cantidad = txtCantidadProductos.getText();

    // Busco si ya agregué anteriormente el producto a la tabla
    boolean productoAgregado = false;
    for (DatosProductosVenta item : datosProductoVenta) {
        if (item.getCodigo().equals(codigo)) {
            item.setCantidad(item.getCantidad() + cantidad);
            item.setImporte(item.getCantidad() * item.getPrecio());

            productoAgregado = true;

            break;
        }
    }

    // Solo si no encontré (si no fue agregado) el producto dentro de la tabla lo cargo de la base de datos
    if (!productoAgregado) {
        String consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Codigo='".concat(txtCodigoProductoBuscar.getText()).concat("'");

        try {
            prep = cn.prepareStatement(consulta);
            result = prep.executeQuery();
            while (result.next()) {
                nombre = result.getString(3);
                tipoAlimento = result.getString(4);
                precio = result.getString(5);
                int precioProducto = Integer.parseInt(precio);
                int cantidadProducto = Integer.parseInt(cantidad);
                importe = String.valueOf(precioProducto * cantidadProducto);

                datosProductoVenta.add(new DatosProductosVenta(codigo, nombre, tipoAlimento, precio, cantidad, importe));

                productoAgregado = true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Alert dialogoAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            dialogoAlert.setTitle("Agregar producto");
            dialogoAlert.setHeaderText(null);
            dialogoAlert.setContentText("El producto no fue encontrado.");
            dialogoAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
            dialogoAlert.showAndWait();
        }
    }

    if (productoAgregado) {
        Alert dialogoAlert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        dialogoAlert.setTitle("Agregar producto");
        dialogoAlert.setHeaderText(null);
        dialogoAlert.setContentText("Producto agregado correctamente.");
        dialogoAlert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        dialogoAlert.showAndWait();
    }
```

**Para esta solución he asumido unas cuantas cosas ya que no las agregas en tu código.**

1 - `datosProductoVenta` es una lista observable de JavaFX cuya declaración en la siguiente: `ObservableList<DatosProductosVenta> datosProductoVenta;`
2 - `tbvDatosProductosVenta` fue declarado de la siguiente manera: `@FXML private TableView<DatosProductosVenta> tbvDatosProductosVenta;` (la anotación puede haberse omitido si la vista no la construyes con FXML)
3 - `datosProductoVenta` tienen una referencia a los elementos de la tabla. Dicha referencia pudo haberse hecho a través de la llamada al método `getItems()` de la tabla `tbvDatosProductosVenta`, de esta manera: `datosProductoVenta = tbvDatosProductosVenta.getItems();`
4 - La clase `DatosProductosVenta` brinda los siguientes métodos:

```
public int getCantidad();
public void setCantidad(int);
public void setImporte(double);
public double getPrecio();
```

Teniendo en consideración lo asumido en los puntos 1 y 3 anteriores, la línea

```
tbvDatosProductosVenta.setItems(datosProductoVenta);
```

que pones después del `catch` no es necesaria.